# Display Date 1 Week Ago & Yesterdays Date

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display 2 dates (local time), the exact date a week ago from today and the exact date yesterday with as little javascript as possible

Examples:

A week ago displayed as `10/07/14`
and a day ago displayed as `10/12/14`

I'm trying to display it in this way

```
<p>The date a week ago was <span id="weekago"></span></p>
        <p>The date yesterday was <span id="yesterday"></span></p>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your JavaScript code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Though it would still take some javascript, you could do it like [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/we63o6cL/):

this helps to retract some days of the Date

```
Date.prototype.subtractDays = function(nrOfDays) {
    var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    return new Date(this - (day * nrOfDays));
}
```

this helps for the formatting (pad left)

```
Object.prototype.padLeft = function(char, nr) {
    var s = this.toString();
    while (s.length < nr) {
        s = char + s;
    }
    return s;
};
```

this formats as you want it

```
Date.prototype.formatStandard = function() {
    return (this.getMonth() + 1).padLeft('0', 2) + '/' +
        (this.getDate()).padLeft('0', 2) + '/' +
        this.getFullYear();
};
```

and this gets the elements containing a datefield (tag name would be datefield), and i opted to rather choose data-value as an attribute to choose which date to show (as you could have more than one weekago or yesterday field)

```
function encodeDateFields() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('datefield'), i, len, item, value;
    if (elems === null || !elems.length) {
        alert('No fields found!');
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
        item = elems[i];
        value = item.getAttribute('data-value');
        switch (value) {
            case 'weekago':
                item.innerHTML = new Date().subtractDays(7).formatStandard();
                break;
            case 'yesterday':
                item.innerHTML = new Date().subtractDays(1).formatStandard();
                break;
            default:
                item.innerHTML = value + ' wasn\'t found!';
        }
    }
}
```

and the function is called onDomReady (with jsfiddle)

```
encodeDateFields();
```

I made the following changes to your html

```
<p>The date a week ago was <span name="datefield" data-value="weekago"></span></p>
<p>The date yesterday was <span name="datefield" data-value="yesterday"></span></p>
```

You would need to code in any extra data-value attributes you might have, like now or tomorrow, but it should be quite obvious where you could do it :)